# Swift ImagePicker VideoCapture didFInishPickingMedia not being called

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, avfoundation, avkit

I'm working on a project which involves video capture. I essentially want to capture video programatically.

I defined the imagepicker and started video capture:

```
if (UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera)) {
            imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
            imagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice.front
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            imagePicker.delegate = self

            //present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: {})
        }
        imagePicker.startVideoCapture()
        print("Capture started")
```

later, I stopped video capture:

```
imagePicker.stopVideoCapture()
    print("capture over")
```

I know this should be calling my method:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    print("captured")


    if let pickedvideo:NSURL = (info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL) {
        let selectorToCall = Selector("videoWasSavedSuccessfully.didFinishSavingWithError:context:")
        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(pickedvideo.relativePath!, self, selectorToCall, nil)

        let videoasset = (AVAsset(url: pickedvideo as URL))
        let playeritem = AVPlayerItem(asset: videoasset)
        let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playeritem)
        let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerViewController.player = player
        self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
            playerViewController.player?.play()
        }
    }
}
```

but the "captured" doesn't get printed, even though I know I'm starting and stopping the recording, as "Capture started" and "Capture over" are printed. I'm not sure why the method isn't being called. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you using the cocoa tag?

Comment: You should check the return value of `startVideoCapture`. Is it returning `true`?

Answer (score -1):

Try setting mediaTypes to kUTTypeMovie.

Comment: What would this have to do with the delegate method being called or not?

Comment: I suggested to add as it was missing media types. At least we should add missing line and check.

Comment: Then this should be a comment, not an answer. But you can't post comments yet. Please don't post comments as answers. Wait until you earn enough reputation to post comments.